# Replacing content between parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What would be the syntax to replace all the content between a set of parentheses using PHP and `preg_replace`.

For example, I would like to remove "`(unknowntext)`" with the following piece of code:

```
$string = 'This text (wont) work';
preg_replace("(unknowntext)", "", $string);
```

Expected output: `This text work`

Comment: I would love to if I had some working solutions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, this won't work for nested parenthesis, so don't expect it to work in those cases.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\([^)]*\)/', '', $string);
```

Comment: It fails for `This text (wont) work (properly)`. It'll return `This text`.

Comment: Now it does. I deleted my answer.

Comment: this does exactly what I need it to.  Thanks